# how to merge chunks of file (result of html5 chunking) into one file fast and efficient

Tags: php, html, file-upload, file-io, file-transfer

I create a file transfer program which upload files (huge file about 4gb) using html5 chunking. each chunk is sized of 100MB (I just choose this for no reason, as I try use 10MB, it does not really have any difference as far as I can tell).

It upload correctly each chunk. but at the end of finish uploading, I try to merge the file back into 1 piece, but it takes so much time. If I try to refresh the web ui for the uploader, it won't work until it finish merging.

my merge code something like this:

```
$final_file_path = fopen($target_path.$file_name, "ab");


//Reconstructed File
for ($i = 0; $i <= $file_total_chunk; $i++) {
    $file_chunk = $target_path.$file_name.$i;    

    if ( $final_file_path ) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = fopen($file_chunk, "rb");
        if ( $in ) {
            //while ( $buff = fread( $in, 1048576 ) ) {
            while ( $buff = fread( $in, 104857600 ) ) {
                fwrite($final_file_path, $buff);
            }   
        }
        if(fclose($in)) {
            unlink($file_chunk);
        }        
    }
}

fclose($final_file_path);
```

Is there anyway to do it efficiently and fast. I'm using PHP.

Thank you

Comment: PHP is the wrong technology for this IMO. I'd look at using `cat` from the commandline and setting up a job queue to handle the process

Comment: I second hafichuk's response.  There's no reason to have PHP read the data if it's not going to do any sort of processing on it.  Use something like `cat` (or `type` on Windows) and append all the files to one result file.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should think about splitting the upload and the concatenation process into two separate processes. The uploading and informing the user that the file has been uploaded (via the web page) can be done together and the backend processing should probably be done in a completely separate process.

I'd look at setting up a job queue to handle the concatenation process, where the PHP upload script, once completed, puts a job in the queue and daemon running on the server spawns a worker to do the concatenation.

Personally, I'd have the worker do the concatenation using `cat`.

```
$> cat chunk_1 chunk_2 ... chunk_n > uploaded_file_name
```

*If* you still wanted to do this in PHP, then you do something like:

```
for ($1 = 0; $i <= $file_total_chunk; $i++) {
    $files[] = $target_path.$file_name.$i;
}

$catCmd = "cat " . implode(" ", $files) . " > " . $final_file_path;
exec($catCmd);
```

Make sure you've sanitized your filenames otherwise it'll be possible to inject arbitrary code that will be executed on the commandline here.

Comment: From php this would be like "exec('cat $chunk_name1 $chunk_name2 ... $chunk_nameN > $uploaded_file_name');"

Comment: @kirugan Thanks, I've added a PHP example to the answer.

Comment: I actually thought about that, but if that's the case, how can I know the file finished merged, so I can sent the download link to the recipient? also, is it normal during merging it takes a huge amouunt of cpu usage (42 files of 100MB, become one file of 4.2GB)

Comment: @hafichuk so, if I'm using php, exec($catCmd); after that command, the script will keep running until it's done, making changing page super slow or impossible I guess. what am I supposed to do here? about worker, do u have example to use worker? thank you

Comment: For the PHP script, you should get a return value from `exec` which will tell you if the job is successful. As for the script timeout, you'll need to adjust the php [timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) (which is another reason not to do this in PHP).

Comment: For the CPU usage/job queue, this is the entire reason to move this into another process. You can control how many jobs are being run concurrently *and* change languages to suit the problem better (cat should use near zero CPU). In terms of tools I'd suggest you look into [gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php) for an [example](http://gearman.org/getting_started). There are a bunch of clients for it (PHP & CLI).

Comment: In terms of your servers, what you're doing isn't trivial *if* you plan on scaling and still being performant. I don't know how big you plan on growing this, but separating your website from file storage is something that you might consider.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to wait when using php with `exec` function, you can use [gearman work queue](http://gearman.org/) with asynchronous response from workers. Inside worker you can use @hafichuk solution. Queue make your whole application more scalable.

Comment: +1'd your answer. I fully support splitting this up into async steps. I also noticed you were pretty busy on SO lately and found some other Q&A's to +1.