# File Upload on unstable internet connection solution

Tags: php, javascript, html, cakephp, file-upload

So I have a file transfer website, which develop using PHP and HTML5. This site supposed to handle huge file transfer (100MB - 4GB file size). The HTML5 mainly is to split the file to smaller size. It works good for stable connection.

However there are several occasion, where the file upload just get cut off due to internet connection suddenly drop off and on for a split second.

My main question would be, is there anyway in php or html5 / javascript.. to handle this type of problem. e.g: maybe if the connection drop off only for couple second, the script will still keep going and when the connection on again, it will continue the file upload ?

or if such thing is impossible, is there anyway to detect the internet got drop off, and show alert("internet got drop"); something like that?

Thank you

Comment: you can send chunks or monitor the bytes sent/received, but it's going to be complicated. you can easily do an error handler on the ajax itself to alert the user.

Comment: you can chack internet conection with js use this code `navigator.onLine` it returns true if is conection and returns false if is not...

Comment: @maxART That is not a reliable way to detect if an internet connection is present.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.onLine#Browser_compatibility

Comment: You can simply retry sending the chunk automatically a set number of times if the request fails, and then allow the user to manually initiate a retry after a set number of auto retries have failed.  In fact, this is what [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) does for you.  Full disclosure: I maintain Fine Uploader.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a recent problem involving large binary signal files over FTP being corrupted by drop-outs. Subsequently, we investigated along with FTP solutions options on the use of web-based uploading similar to the sort of handling you seem to be looking for. The most robust solution remains the use of an rsync implementation and a continuous checksum.

That said, the option that seems to be missing directly from the HTML5 API is to be able to send a hash or checksum of the chunk in the chunk itself so that the verification that the data blob has been received intact is done transparently.

You should essentially be able this by doing some processing on the slice data and combining this with the blob before then sending.

```
            while( start < SIZE ) {
                var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);
                //var chunkHash = chunk.ComputeHash(); // e.g. CRC32 or Adler
                //chunk = chunkHash + chunk
                uploadFile(chunk);
                start = end;
                end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
            }
```

At the other end you pull the first n bytes and compute the hash on the rest then compare the first n bytes with your data.

Some articles for inspiration: 
[uploading a file in chunks using html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853467/uploading-a-file-in-chunks-using-html5) is a good place I think to look at handling the file uploads
[how to merge chunks of file (result of html5 chunking) into one file fast and efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205445/how-to-merge-chunks-of-file-result-of-html5-chunking-into-one-file-fast-and-ef?rq=1)

Finally, probably worth investigating pre-existing libraries and doing some 'drop-out' testing to identify the best performing. http://www.plupload.com/ seems to have some following (not affiliated and untested for this purpose).

Comment: Calculating a hash client side is really not worth the hassle.  Such an operation is quite inneficient and will significantly impact performance of your app, especially when large files are involved.

Comment: Agree that performance wise a hash on the client side is not ideal. However, where data integrity is concerned the strategy is not driven by performance. I'm presuming that the connection itself is significantly slower than the time to process a hash on a chunk.